# Find the number of real root of $x^{4}+2 x^{3}-5=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, roots

Find the number of real roots of $x^{4}+2 x^{3}-5=0$.

I draw graph of this equation,  this equation have two roots but are these roots real ? I also find $x=1,-1 ,0, 2, -2 $ are not root's.

Comment: "but are these roots real?" Do you know what "real root" means?

Comment: @Arthur root in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: When you draw a function in $x,y$ then the values where the function crosses the $X-axis$ are the real roots.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, there must be $4$ total roots.

Now, look up Descartes's rule of signs: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Descartes'_rule_of_signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Descartes%27_rule_of_signs)

Applying this rule for positive real root finding,
$$
f(x) = x^4 + 2x^3 - 5
$$
we see that coefficients have one sign change (from $2x^3$ to $-5$), since it cannot be smaller than one by the even number it has exactly one positive root (equal to the number of sign changes).

Now for the negative real root finding, consider $f(-x)$,
$$
f(-x) = x^4 - 2x^3 -5
$$
conveniently, it has one sign change again (from $x^4$ to the next). So, exactly one negative real root.

So we have $2$ real roots, one positive and one negative.
The other two roots must be imaginary.

Answer (score 2):

The following proof is a *sketch*. Can you see/fill in the details of each step. [I trust that you can because one of the tags is calculus.]

1. The number of real roots of $f(x)=x^4+2x^3-5$ is either 0,2,or 4.
2. Note that the derivative $f'$ of $f$ is $f'=4x^3+6x^2 = x^2(4x+6)$ is 0 for exactly 2 values of $x$.
3. Also note that between any two distinct consecutive real roots $x_1$ and $x_2$, there has to be a $y_{12}$ satisfying $f'(y_{12})=0$.
4. However, $f(0) < 0$ whereas $f(10) > 0$ and so is $f(-10)>0$. So $f$ has to have at least 2 real roots, the first strictly between $x=-10$ and $x=0$, and the second strictly between $x=0$ and $x=10$.

So 2. and 3. together imply that there cannot be 4 real roots, if there were, $f'$ would have to be 0 for at least 3 values of $x$. However, 4. implies that there has to be at least 2 real roots.

So that leaves us with precisely 2 real roots.